# Vue JS - How to add pixels on the left side when scrolling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, scroll

I want to make it so that when scrolling, the block with the block-1 class changes its position to the right, that is, when scrolling, it moves to the right by 1 pixel

Here is the given [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-mendeleev-tn1qu)

```
 <template>
      <div>
        <div class="scroll-block">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quod at
          vitae explicabo unde expedita ullam, excepturi accusantium aut aperiam
          adipisci consectetur corrupti, perspiciatis, earum ad modi recusandae
          numquam tenetur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
          Corrupti distinctio architecto deleniti quas nihil. Illum possimus
          accusamus quibusdam quis, repudiandae labore laboriosam nihil odit, vitae
          ratione numquam quod cumque aut.
        </div>
    
        <div class="block-1"></div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <style scoped>
    .scroll-block {
      width: 200px;
      overflow: scroll;
      height: 200px;
      background: red;
    }
    .block-1 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: yellow;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just handle scrolling event and change the box position.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="scroll-block" @scroll="onScroll">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quod at
      vitae explicabo unde expedita ullam, excepturi accusantium aut aperiam
      adipisci consectetur corrupti, perspiciatis, earum ad modi recusandae
      numquam tenetur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
      Corrupti distinctio architecto deleniti quas nihil. Illum possimus
      accusamus quibusdam quis, repudiandae labore laboriosam nihil odit, vitae
      ratione numquam quod cumque aut.
    </div>

    <div class="block-1" :style="block1Style"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      block1Left: 0,
      timerId: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    block1Style() {
      return {
        left: `${this.block1Left}px`,
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onScroll() {
      this.block1Left++;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.scroll-block {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.block-1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
```

Comment: nice move with @scroll learned from that. ty

Comment: Thanks for the answer and how to make it so that the value decreases by one during the backward scroll

Comment: You should add a ref to your scroll-block element, keep the element's scrollTop value and compare it with a new scrollTop value in the onScroll handler. Then you can decide should you move block-1 left or right.